Pattern matching in ruby with hashes
When i was learning about pattern matching in ruby, i came across this issue
hash = { name: 1, age: 21, location: "NYC" }
case hash
in {name: String => x, age:y, location:z}
    puts "Name: #{x}, Age: #{y}, Location: #{z}"
in {name: x, age:y}
    puts "Name: #{x}, Age: #{y}"
else
    puts "Invalid pattern"
end 

In the above code, i expected Invalid pattern to be printed on the screen(since the name keyword value is an integer), but when i ran in in replit, the value printed on the console was Name: 1, Age: 21
How does this happen?
For the second in condition, the hash must only have name and age, but in the hash provided, it has name, age and location

first does not match probably because of string type, second matches because name and age are present, it's not required presense only 2 key-values

Hash patterns by default ignore extra keys in the matched value, except for empty hash pattern which only matches the empty hash.
If you want to exactly match a non-empty Hash, you can add **nil to the pattern:
Change:
in {name: x, age: y}

to:
in {name: x, age: y, **nil}

and your code will print "Invalid pattern".
It's documented here.
